Salutations not getting removed within jQuery statement
I'm new to jQuery, but can't understand where I'm going wrong
I have a text field for a full name with ID "class_name"
I have a text field for a generated username with ID "class_add"
I'm trying to do a regex within jQuery to remove all instances of Mr, Ms, Mrs, Miss

with and without the . at the end of the salutations

<form action="/mod.php" method="post" class="form-modern">
  <div class="block-inner" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <input class="form-input" id="class_name" type="text" name="class_name" data-constraints="@Required" required>
      <label class="form-label" for="class_name">Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <input class="form-input" id="class_add" type="text" name="class_add" placeholder="Username" data-constraints="@Required" required>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" name="assign_class" type="submit">Create</button>
  </div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class_name').on('input', function() {
    str = $('#class_name');
    var text = str.text().replace(/^(Mr\.*\s+|Miss\.*\s+|Mrs\.*\s+|Ms\.*\s+)*(.*)$/is, '');
    var firstChar = str.val().substr(0, 1);
    var lastChars = str.val().split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    var lastChars = lastChars.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var actual = firstChar + '.' + lastChars;
    $('#class_add').empty();
    $('#class_add').attr("value", actual).css("text-transform","lowercase");
  });
});

This however isn't removing anything matched in the #class_add field
If I omit the regex for the search and type in 'John Doe' the suggested username will be j.doe -- this part works. Although I'm sure the code could be refined, however I'm completely new to this
However if someone types in 'Mr John Doe' or 'Mr. John Doe' I'd like the salutations to be completely removed.
UPDATE:
Not sure if it were a regex issue, or the way it's formatted using jQuery, however in any case sorted the issue going back and forth between console log.
Code is below for reference, if it helps anyone else.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class_name').on('input', function() {
    str = $('#class_name'); const regex = /^M((r)|iss|(s))\.*/;
    var text = $.trim(str.val().replace(regex, ''));
    if (text.length > 1) {
      var firstChar = text.substr(0, 1);
      var lastChars = text.split(' ').slice(1).join(' '); var lastChars = lastChars.replace(/\s+/g, '');
      var actual = firstChar + '.' + lastChars;
      $('#class_add').attr("value", actual).css("text-transform","lowercase");
    }
    else { $('#class_add').attr("value", ''); }
  });
});

If there's a way to simplify this code I'm all ears and I'd love to learn other ways to do the same functions

Does str.val() give you the expected value?   (add console.log(str) after you set it and check the console).   If you have class='class_name' then use $(".class_name") not #

Can you add the related source code,as others have said we need to check if class_name is an id or class property

Do not quote the regex literal: '/a/g' != /a/g. Just FYI: ^ and $ in your regex enforce the whole string match, you need to remove them if you plan to remove a part of the string.

^^^ in your case:  .replace('/^(Mr becomes .replace(/^(Mr

@WiktorStribiżew It might has nothing to do with regex, as OP said he is newbie for jQuery

Sorry, should have noted. It's an id

Your "also tried" regex is not the same as it doesn't check for a space after the salutation.   Also, do you mean to replace the entire string or just the Mr/Mrs part?  Your question could do with some sample inputs and expected outputs as "a generated username" is unclear if it starts with spaces or not.

Please [edit] to include the HTML - would clear up that issue immediately.

Post edited to reflect more of what I'm trying to get across. Sorry.

Solved the issue. Seems regex is a slightly different approach coming from PHP, and different again when formatting for jQuery and Javascript. Updated code in main post.

I'm all ears Protips: match your variable names to what they contain, eg str = $('#class_name')  - this is not a string.  Put each "command" on its own line.  Don't use deprecated jquery functions when they (now) existing in most JS engines $.trim(str) -> str.trim().  Use css classes rather than .css.
